# Pandas Pivot Table- aggfunc to get subtotals on a multi-Index?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a simple dataframe with an index I need to group on- continent:

```
 country   continent   value1   value2   value3  
 uk        eu               1        9        2  
 us        na               8       39        0  
 spain     eu               3        9        0  
 mexico    na               2        7        8  
 japan     asia             9        9        2  
 china     asia             2        8        6
```

All I'm looking to do is create a dataframe that creates rows for continents and incorporates their subtotals as a value, and then adds Grand total at the end and incorporates the totals for each column.

```
 Row Labels    Sum of value1   Sum of value2   Sum of value3  
 asia                     11              17               8  
 china                     2               8               6  
 japan                     9               9               2  
 eu                        4              18               2  
 spain                     3               9               0  
 uk                        1               9               2  
 na                       10              46               8  
 mexico                    2               7               8  
 us                        8              39               0  
 Grand Total              25              81              18
```

This is my code, and for some reason I can only get the grand total with the aggfunc, not subtotals as well.

```
pd.pivot_table(mergedcpt, index=['continent','spread_Bucket'],aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True)


  eu      uk     1    9    2   
          us        8   39    0  
  na     spain     3    9    0  
         mexico    2    7    8  
  asia   japan     9    9    2  
         china     2    8    6  
  all             25   81   18
```

What am I getting wrong? Appreciate the help- I know previous pandas versions incorporated rows you could aggregate, but I don't know how to do this in the new version. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Why not groupby `continent` and sum the columns. Then append to that another groupby `country` and sum the columns.

Comment: I could, but then instead of the name 'Total' I would have to name it something like 'EU total', plus it would be hard to format nicely so that subtotals were at the bottom.

Comment: also how would I do that groupby? I would loc by continent and then groupby sum, but then I would have to manually assign each total a continent right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no quick one-liner for what you are trying to do.  You can create a new data frame by grouping on the continents, append the original data frame, and sort the values to get the order you want.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'continent': ['eu', 'na', 'eu', 'na', 'asia', 'asia'],
     'country': ['uk', 'us', 'spain', 'mexico', 'japan', 'china'],
     'value1': [1, 8, 3, 2, 9, 2],
     'value2': [9, 39, 9, 7, 9, 8],
     'value3': [2, 0, 0, 8, 2, 6]})

g = df.groupby(['continent','continent']).sum()
g.index.set_names('Row Label', level=-1, inplace=True)
gt = pd.DataFrame([g.sum()], columns=g.columns,
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('~','Grand Total')]))
df2 = g.append(gt).reset_index()
out = ( df2.append(df.rename(columns={'country': 'Row Label'})
                     .sort_values(['continent', 'Row Label']))
           .sort_values('continent')
           .drop('continent', axis=1)
           .rename(columns={'value1': 'Sum of value1',
                            'value2': 'Sum of value2',
                            'value3': 'Sum of value3'})
           .reset_index(drop=True) )
out
# returns:
     Row Label  Sum of value1  Sum of value2  Sum of value3
0         asia             11             17              8
1        china              2              8              6
2        japan              9              9              2
3           eu              4             18              2
4        spain              3              9              0
5           uk              1              9              2
6           na             10             46              8
7       mexico              2              7              8
8           us              8             39              0
9  Grand Total             25             81             18
```

Comment: that is exactly what I needed- thanks so much for the help

Comment: please remember to mark the question as answered as well.